# Hint HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH reduces the amount of Entities returned per page for a PageRequest down to below the configured page size (PostgreSQL)

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data, repository

I'm setting up a JPA Specification based repository implementation that utilizes jpa specifications(constructed based on RSQL filter strings) to filter the results, define result ordering and remove any duplicates via "distinct" that would otherwise be returned due to joined tables. The JPA Specification builder method joins several tables and sets the "distinct" flag:

```
final Join<Object, Object> rootJoinedTags = root.join("tags", JoinType.LEFT);
final Join<Object, Object> rootJoinedLocations = root.join("location", JoinType.LEFT);
...
query.distinct(true);
```

To allow sorting by joined table columns, I've applied the "HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH" hint to the relevant repository method(otherwise, sorting by joined table columns returns an error along the lines of "sort column must be included in the SELECT DISTINCT query").

```
@QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false")
    })
    Page<SomeEntity> findAll(@Nullable Specification<SomeEntity> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

The arguments for said repository method are constructed as such:

```
final Sort sort = getSort(searchFilter);
        final Specification spec = getSpecificationIfPresent(searchFilter);
        final PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(searchFilter.getPageNumber(), searchFilter.getLimit(), sort);

        return eventRepository.findAll(spec, pageRequest);
```

After those changes, filtering and sorting seem to work as expected. However, the hint seems to cause "distinct" filtering to be applied after the result page is already constructed, thus reducing the number of returned entities in the page from the configured "size" PageRequest argument, to whatever is left after the duplicates are filtered out. For example, if we'd make a PageRequest with "page=0" and "pageSize=10", then the resulting Page may return only 5 "SomeEntity" instances, although the database contains way more entries(177 entities to be exact in this case). If I remove the hint, then the returned entities number is correct again.

Question: is there a way to make the same Specification query setup work with correctly sized Pages(some other hints that might be added to have duplicate filtering performed before the Page object is constructed)? If not, then is there another approach I could use to achieve the required Specification-based filtering, with joined-column sorting and duplicate removal as with "distinct"?

PS: PostgreSQL is the database behind the application in question

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Estophyl I'm also interested in any answer to this, I've posted this question on the hibernate forums as well: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hint-hint-pass-distinct-through-reduces-the-amount-of-entities-returned-per-page-for-a-pagerequest-down-to-below-the-configured-page-size-postgresql/3869

Answer (score 8):

The problem you are experimenting have to do with the way you are using the `HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` hint.

This hint allows you to indicate Hibernate that the `DISTINCT` keyword should not be used in the `SELECT` statement issued against the database.

You are taking advantage of this fact to allow your queries to be sorted by a field that is not included in the `DISTINCT` column list.

But that is not how this hint should be used.

This hint only must be used when you are sure that there will be no difference between applying or not a `DISTINCT` keyword to the SQL `SELECT` statement, because the `SELECT` statement already will fetch all the distinct values *per se*. The idea is improve the performance of the query avoiding the use of an unnecessary `DISTINCT` statement.

This is usually what will happen when you use the `query.distinct` method in you criteria queries, and you are `join fetching` child relationships. [This great article](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpql-distinct-jpa-hibernate/) of @VladMihalcea explain how the hint works in detail.

On the other hand, when you use paging, it will set `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` - or something similar, depending on the underlying database - in the SQL `SELECT` statement issued against the database, limiting to a maximum number of results your query.

As stated, if you use the `HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` hint, the `SELECT` statement will not contain the `DISTINCT` keyword and, because of your joins, it could potentially give duplicate records of your main entity. This records will be processed by Hibernate to differentiate duplicates, because you are using `query.distinct`, and it will in fact remove duplicates if needed. I think this is the reason why you may get less records than requested in your `Pageable`.

If you remove the hint, as the `DISTINCT` keyword is passed in the SQL statement which is sent to the database, as far as you only project information of the main entity, it will fetch all the records indicated by `LIMIT` and this is why it will give you always the requested number of records.

You can try and `fetch join` your child entities (instead of only `join` with them). It will eliminate the problem of not being able to use the field you need to sort by in the columns of the `DISTINCT` keyword and, in addition, you will be able to apply, now legitimately, the hint.

But if you do so it will you another problem: if you use join fetch and pagination, to return the main entities and its collections, Hibernate will no longer apply pagination at database level - it will no include `OFFSET` or `LIMIT` keywords in the SQL statement, and it will try to paginate the results in memory. This is the famous Hibernate `HHH000104` warning:

```
HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
```

@VladMihalcea explain that in great detail in the last part of [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/query-pagination-jpa-hibernate/) article.

He also proposed one possible solution to your problem, [Window Functions](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-definitely-learn-sql-window-functions/).

In you use case, instead of using `Specification`s, the idea is that you implement your own DAO. This DAO only need to have access to the `EntityManager`, which is not a great deal as you can inject your `@PersistenceContext`:

```java
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;
```

Once you have this `EntityManager`, you can create native queries and use window functions to build, based on the provided `Pageable` information, the right SQL statement that will be issued against the database. This will give you a lot of more freedom about what fields use for sorting or whatever you need.

As the last cited article indicates, Window Functions is a feature supported by all mayor databases.

In the case of PostgreSQL, you can easily come across them in the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html).

Finally, one more option, suggested in fact by @nickshoe, and explained in great detail in the [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/) he cited, is to perform the sorting and paging process in two phases: in the first phase, you need to create a query that will reference your child entities and in which you will apply paging and sorting. This query will allow you to identify the ids of the main entities that will be used, in the second phase of the process, to obtain the main entities themselves.

You can take advantage of the aforementioned custom DAO to accomplish this process.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an off-topic answer, but it may help you.

You could try to tackle this problem (pagination of parent-child entities) by separating the query in two parts:

- a query for retrieving the ids that match the given criteria
- a query for retrieving the actual entities by the resulting ids of the previous query

I came across this solution in this blog post: https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/