# Pass single Join instance to multiple Specification instances?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Related: [Hint HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH reduces the amount of Entities returned per page for a PageRequest down to below the configured page size (PostgreSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921415/hint-hint-pass-distinct-through-reduces-the-amount-of-entities-returned-per-page)

I'm setting up a JPA Specification based repository implementation that utilizes jpa specifications(constructed based on RSQL filter strings) to filter the results, define result ordering and remove any duplicates via "distinct" that would otherwise be returned due to joined tables. The JPA Specification builder method joins several tables and sets the "distinct" flag:

```
public final class MySpec implements Specification<Tag>
{
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(
        final Root<Tag> root,
        final CriteriaQuery<?> query,
        final CriteriaBuilder builder)
    {

        final Join<Tag, Label> labelsJoin = root.join("labels", JoinType.INNER);
        final Join<Label, LabelIdentity> labelIdentityJoin = labelsJoin.join("labelIdentity", JoinType.INNER);
        final Predicate labelKeyPredicate = builder.equal(labelIdentityJoin.get("key"), property);

        query.distinct(true);

        return builder.and(
                    labelKeyPredicate,
                    builder.like(labelsJoin.get("value"), argument.replace('*', '%')));
    }
}
```

To allow sorting by joined table columns, I've applied the "HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH" hint to the relevant repository method(otherwise, sorting by joined table columns returns an error along the lines of "sort column must be included in the SELECT DISTINCT query").

After those changes, filtering and sorting seems to work as required. However, the hint seems to cause "distinct" filtering to be applied after the result page is already constructed, thus reducing the number of returned entities in the page from the configured "size" PageRequest argument, to whatever is left after the duplicates are filtered out.

My question is:

Is it possible to remove the need to use distinct (and thus solve the paging issue) by somehow reusing the `Join` instances amoung different `Specification` instances? For example construct the `Join` instances, and pass the same `Join` instance into each new Specification instance (e.g. via the constuctor)?

For example, I've tried to create something like the following, and then passed this `JoinCache` instance into each `Specification` instance, however, I got errors about incorrect alias, so not sure if something like this is even supported?

```
public class JoinCache
{
    private final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;

    private final CriteriaQuery<Tag> criteriaQuery;

    private final Root<Tag> tagRoot;

    private final Join<Tag, Label> labelJoin;

    private final Join<Label, LabelIdentity> labelIdentityJoin;

    public JoinCache(final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder)
    {
        this.criteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilder;
        this.criteriaQuery = this.criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tag.class);
        this.tagRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Tag.class);
        this.labelJoin = tagRoot.join("labels", JoinType.INNER);
        this.labelIdentityJoin = labelJoin.join("labelIdentity", JoinType.INNER);
    }

    public Join<Tag, Label> getLabelJoin()
    {
        return labelJoin;
    }

    public Join<Label, LabelIdentity> getLabelIdentityJoin()
    {
        return labelIdentityJoin;
    }

    public CriteriaBuilder getCriteriaBuilder()
    {
        return criteriaBuilder;
    }

    public CriteriaQuery<Tag> getCriteriaQuery()
    {
        return criteriaQuery;
    }

    public Root<Tag> getTagRoot()
    {
        return tagRoot;
    } 
}
```

**Update**

An alternative approach using subqueries instead of joins (thus avoiding the need to use distinct at all), however, I believe order by/sorting in subqueries are not supported in JPA specifications:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-256

```
public class MySpec implements Specification<Tag>
{
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(
        final Root<Tag> root,
        final CriteriaQuery<?> query,
        final CriteriaBuilder builder)
    {
        final String argument = arguments.get(0);

        final Subquery<Label> subQuery = query.subquery(Label.class);

        final Root<Label> subRoot = subQuery.from(Label.class);

        final Predicate tagPredicate = builder.equal(subRoot.get("tag"), root);

        final Predicate labelKeyPredicate = builder.equal(subRoot.get("labelIdentity").get("key"), "owner");

        subQuery.select(subRoot).where(tagPredicate, labelKeyPredicate, builder.like(subRoot.get("value"), argument.replace('*', '%'));

        return builder.exists(subQuery);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad practice to create reusable predicates with side effects on external query (I mean `query.distinct(true)`). You can achieve the same result using `subquery` and `exists` predicate.

Supposing `Tag` entity has `@Id Long id` field

```
public final class MySpec implements Specification<Tag> {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(
        final Root<Tag> root,
        final CriteriaQuery<?> query,
        final CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class); // if entity id has Long type
        Root<Tag> subRoot = subquery.from(Tag.class);

        final Join<Tag, Label> label = subRoot.join("labels", JoinType.INNER);
        final Join<Label, LabelIdentity> labelIdentity = label.join("labelIdentity", JoinType.INNER);

        final Predicate externalQueryJoinPredicate =
            builder.equal(subRoot.get("id"), root.get("id"));
        final Predicate labelKeyPredicate = 
            builder.equal(labelIdentity.get("key"), property);
        final Predicate labelValuePredicate = 
            builder.like(label.get("value"), argument.replace('*', '%'));

        subquery.select(subRoot.get("id")).where( 
            externalQueryJoinPredicate, labelKeyPredicate, labelValuePredicate);

        return builder.exists(subquery);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alex valuiskyi, I've actually tried subqueries (I've updated my question to include this), however, I believe order by/sorting on subqueries is not supported in JPA specifications: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-256

Comment: Another approach is to make joins for `order by` statement by separate predicate and use subqueries predicates in `where` statement. `query.distinct(true)` should be set on a higher level if it necessary